# Getting frames from phone with opencv

Tags: android, opencv

I am trying to get frames from my phone's camera and use them for image processing with `opencv`. I can use methods of `opencv` like `Mat()` but when i try to use `VideoCapture` class i am having some troubles.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.toshba.circletry, PID: 32522
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
Native method not found: org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture.VideoCapture_3:()J
```

this is what I get :

I tried to use `CameraBridgeViewBase` but couldn't find how to get frames by using it. Which one can I use. Can you suggest a tutorial about this or a solution to my error.

I've been searching for days and literally tried most of the solutions.(btw I am newbie on `Android` and working on `Android Studio`)
Thanks.

Finally my code here :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "Something";

static {

try {

System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        Log.v("ERROR", "" + e);
    }
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.i(TAG, "Trying to load OpenCV library");
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_1_0, this, mOpenCVCallBack))
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot connect to OpenCV Manager");
    }
    else{ Log.i(TAG, "opencv successfull");
        System.out.println(java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()); }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
public void process()
{

    Mat frameCapture = new Mat();
    VideoCapture videoDevice = new VideoCapture();
    videoDevice.open(0);

    if (videoDevice.isOpened()) {

        while (true) {

            videoDevice.read(frameCapture);
            HoughCircles(frameCapture);
        }

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Video aygýtýna baðlanýlamadý.");
        return;
    }
}
public void HoughCircles( Mat originalMat)
{
    Mat grayMat = new Mat();
    Mat cannyEdges = new Mat();
    Mat circles = new Mat();

    Imgproc.cvtColor(originalMat,grayMat,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.Canny(grayMat,cannyEdges,10,100);
    Imgproc.HoughCircles(cannyEdges,circles,Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,cannyEdges.rows()/15);
    Mat houghCircles = new Mat();
    houghCircles.create(cannyEdges.rows(),cannyEdges.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    for(int i=0;i<circles.cols();i++)
    {
        double[] parameters = circles.get(0,i);
        double x,y;
        int r;
        x=parameters[0];
        y=parameters[1];
        r= (int)parameters[2];

        Point center = new Point(x,y);

        Imgproc.circle(houghCircles,center,r,new Scalar(255,0,0),1);
    }
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(houghCircles.cols(), houghCircles.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(houghCircles, bm);

    // find the imageview and draw it!
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bm);


}
private BaseLoaderCallback mOpenCVCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                process();


            } break;


            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};

}
```

Comment: did you try http://opencv.org/platforms/android/opencv4android-samples.html ?

Comment: I 've looked them but they  don't use videocapture class